# Why does numpy not short-circuit on non-contiguous arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, short-circuiting

Consider the following simple test:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

a = np.random.randint(0,2,1000000,bool)
```

Let us find the index of the first `True`

```
timeit(lambda:a.argmax(), number=1000)
# 0.000451055821031332
```

This is reasonably fast because `numpy` short-circuits.

It also works on contiguous slices,

```
timeit(lambda:a[1:-1].argmax(), number=1000)
# 0.0006490410305559635
```

But not, it seems, on non-contiguous ones. I was mainly interested in finding the last `True`:

```
timeit(lambda:a[::-1].argmax(), number=1000)
# 0.3737605109345168
```

> **UPDATE:** My assumption that the observed slowdown was due to not short circuiting is inaccurate (thanks @Victor Ruiz). Indeed, in the
>   worst-case scenario of an all `False` array

```
b=np.zeros_like(a)
timeit(lambda:b.argmax(), number=1000)
# 0.04321779008023441
```

> we are still an order of magnitude faster than in the non-contiguous
>   case. I'm ready to accept Victor's explanation that the actual culprit
>   is a copy being made (timings of forcing a copy with `.copy()` are
>   suggestive). Afterwards it doesn't really matter anymore whether
>   short-circuiting happens or not.

But other step sizes != 1 yield similar behavior.

```
timeit(lambda:a[::2].argmax(), number=1000)
# 0.19192566303536296
```

Question: Why does `numpy` not short-circuit **UPDATE** *without making a copy* in the last two examples?

And, more importantly: Is there a workaround, i.e. some way to force `numpy` to short-ciruit **UPDATE** *without making a copy* also on non-contiguous arrays?

Comment: I vaguely recall looking at this short-circuiting for a SO quite some time ago.  It applies to bool and the `nan` in floats.  I think it's implemented at a very low level in the C code,  So Victor's idea that your strides creates a copy makes some sense.

Comment: Choosing a good test subject for short-circuiting can be tricky.  Do you want it to quit early in the iteration, around the middle, or way at the end.  Timings vary if it does short circuit.

Comment: @hpaulj _"So Victor's idea that your strides creates a copy makes some sense."_ The timings certainly support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got interested in solving this problem. So I`ve come with the next solution that manages to avoid the "`a[::-1]`" problem case due to internal ndarray copies by `np.argmax`:

I created a small library that implements a function [`argmax`](https://github.com/Vykstorm/numpy-bool-argmax-ext/blob/master/argmaxext/__init__.py#L9) which is a wrapper of `np.argmax`, but it has increased performance when the input argument is a 1D boolean array with stride value set to -1:

https://github.com/Vykstorm/numpy-bool-argmax-ext

For those cases, it uses a low-level C routine to find the index `k` of an item with maximum value (`True`), starting from the end to the beginning of the array `a`. 
 Then you can compute `argmax(a[::-1])` with `len(a)-k-1`

The low-level method doesn't perform any internal ndarray copies because it operates with the array `a` which is already C-contiguous and aligned in memory. It also applies short-circuit

---

EDIT:
I extended the library to improve the performance `argmax` also when dealing with stride values different than -1 (with 1D boolean arrays) with good results: `a[::2]`, `a[::-3]`, e.t.c.

Give it a try.

Comment: Nice! Any reason not to do it for arbitrary stride? And to make a PR at numpy proper?

Comment: I thought it wasnt a good solution for general strides because the algorithm will not take advantage of spacial locality (if the stride is big). But i can give it a try.

Comment: You still have the benefit of short circuiting (compared to the copy operation). Also according to the gurus [hardware prefetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47714514/7207392) is rather good these days.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I didnt made a PR because i just learnt cpython while doing the library and im not an expert of numpy

Answer (score 11):

The problem is related with the memory alignment of the array when using strides.
Either `a[1:-1]`, `a[::-1]` are considered aligned in memory but `a[::2]`
dont:

```py
a = np.random.randint(0,2,1000000,bool)

print(a[1:-1].flags.c_contiguous) # True
print(a[::-1].flags.c_contiguous) # False
print(a[::2].flags.c_contiguous) # False
```

This explains why `np.argmax` is slow on `a[::2]` (from documentation on [ndarrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/source/reference/arrays.ndarray.rst#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray)):

> Several algorithms in NumPy work on arbitrarily strided arrays. However, some algorithms require single-segment arrays. When an irregularly strided array is passed in to such algorithms, a copy is automatically made.

`np.argmax(a[::2])` is making a copy of the array. So if you do `timeit(lambda: np.argmax(a[::2]), number=5000)` you are timing 5000 copies of the array `a`

Execute this and compare the results of this two timing calls:

```py
print(timeit(lambda: np.argmax(a[::2]), number=5000))

b = a[::2].copy()
print(timeit(lambda: np.argmax(b), number=5000))
```

---

EDIT: 
Digging into the source code in C of numpy, i found the underline implementation of `argmax` function, [PyArray_ArgMax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_ArgMax) which calls at some point to [PyArray_ContiguousFromAny](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_ContiguousFromAny) to ensure that the given input array is aligned in memory (C-style)

Then, if the dtype of the array is bool, it delegates to [BOOL_argmax](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6ca558fef265b6d286e1868a7bea5723a503a8ba/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L3036) function.
Looking at its code, seems that short-ciruit is **always** applied.

### Summary

- In order to avoid copies by `np.argmax`, make sure that the input array is contiguous in memory
- short-circuit is always applied when data type is boolean.

Comment: The copy I'm buying, but what exactly is the point of this reshape thing?

Comment: I suspected that was your reasoning. But, alas, it's wrong. The rows are not interleaved. The first row contains the first half a million entries and the second row contains the second half a million entries. What you want to achieve would require reshape to (-1,2) and then argmax along axis zero, but it doesn't make things faster.

Comment: Ok. Im removing that from my post